# Combining two formulas

Tags: excel

I am using the following formula

```
=MAX(OFFSET(IF($B7="A",Sheet1!$BQ$5,IF($B7="B",Sheet2!$BQ$5,IF($B7="C",Sheet3!$BQ$5,IF($B7="D",Sheet4!$BQ$5)))),MATCH($G7,IF($B7="A",Sheet1!$G$6:$G$60,IF($B7="B",Sheet2!$G$6:$G$60,IF($B7="C",Sheet3!$G$6:$G$60,IF($B7="D",Sheet4!$G$6:$G$60)))),0),0,1,10))
```

but want the cell reference $BQ$5 to be dynamically referenced using this formula (which works).

```
="$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(JQ$5,Number!5:5,0),4),1,"")&"$5"
```

When I try to drop the second formula in place of the cell reference in the first formula, Excel doesn't like it.

How can I merge the second formula into the first?

Comment: Are UDFs in play, or does this have to be all through formulas?

Comment: Trying to keep it to formulas. I used a workaround in the end using the second formula to generate the list, then referenced those cells in the first formula. Would still like to know how to merge them if it's possible though. I tried using an INDIRECT() but that didn't work, surprisingly.

Comment: Looking at your second formula why don't you just use `ADDRESS(5,MATCH(JQ$5,Number!5:5,0),1)` to give the absolute reference directly?    With regard to the error you are getting from the first formula, are you using INDIRECT, e.g.`...INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(5,MATCH(JQ$5,Number!5:5,0),1))...`.  I think this should work.